# Как сделать клик по li последующим переходом на страницу, исключить определенную область клика?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Нужно сделать для li возможность перехода на страницу, но чтобы в определенной области этого li переход не делался, как сделать?

```
$('.id_order_line').bind('click', function () {
    id_order_click = $(this).data('id_order_click');
    document.location.href='/order/details-'+ id_order_click +'';
});
```

Comment: Предлагать пользователю читать лицензионное соглашение, в котором четко прописывать ответственность пользователя за клик в ненужной области.
  
Вы бы хоть пояснили, где делать клик, где нет. Можно даже наглядно продемонстрировать, что именно у вас реализовано (jsfiddle.net).

Comment: А нельзя вставить в li блок div нужной длины с нужными отступами, и на него уже повесить событие click.

Comment: Так и сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение http://jsfiddle.net/euma9Lvx/4/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Покликай по всей длинне 1</li>
    <li>Покликай по всей длинне 2</li>
    <li>Покликай по всей длинне 3</li>
    <li>Покликай по всей длинне 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top:10px;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

JavaScript

```
/*
x - координата x - верхнего левого угла
y - координата y - верхнего левого угла
width - ширина
height - высота
*/
var x = 100;
var y = 5;
var width = 200; 
var height = 15;

$('li').click(function(e){
    console.log(e)
    var x_click = e.offsetX == undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerX : e.offsetX;
    var y_click = e.offsetY == undefined ? e.originalEvent.layerY : e.offsetY;
    if ((x_click >= x) && (x_click <= (x+width)) && (y_click >= y) && (y_click <= (y + height))){
        alert('Ты попал в меня!!!! - ' +$(this).text());
    }
})
```